# bash and nohup capture

Tags: bash, shell

I have an scp script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r /usr/local/htdocs/$1 httpd@$2:/local/htdocs
```

I want to call it from the command line, and pass a directory, and destination server, similar to this:

```
move_site.sh website  servername
```

However, I want to capture the output in a file containing the 2 parameters.

So I tried this, but it didn't print anything when calling using nohup

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r /usr/local/htdocs/$1 httpd@$2:/local/htdocs > $1$1.out
```

How can I structure both the script and the calling command so that it runs in the background, and captures the output based on destination and site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should work, but maybe there is an error while trying to *scp*, that's why your output file is empty? To capture error messages to output file aswell, change `>` to `>&`:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r /usr/local/htdocs/$1 httpd@$2:/local/htdocs >& $1$2.out
```

To run your script in background, simply add `&` at the end of a command:

```
move_site.sh website  servername &
```

P.S. *website* and *servername* should not include any characters, that are not allowed in a file name if you insist on using them in `$1$2.out` form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass two or more words as a single parameter, you have to wrap it with quotes:

```
$ cat s.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "param1: $1, param2: $2"
```

So we get:

```
$ ./s.sh "a b" c
param1: a b, param2: c
```

Following this example, you have to adapt your script in consequence.